# Why am I getting 404 on my web service locally

Tags: asp.net, wcf, http-status-code-404

I am working with a web service written using .NET wcf.  When running locally, I can go to the wsdl by going to the url of the svc file but I get a 404 error when I try to go to one of the service methods ex Api.svc/GetPrice

Any thoughts about what could be causing this?  The service is running on production.  (I just need to fix a bug with the data.)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say based on the information you've provided, but have you tried to [ensure that IIS and WCF are correctly installed and registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx)? I've forgotten to do this before and I believe it results in a 404.